# Using custom middlware in Loopback (Strongloop)

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am learning how to use custom middlewares properly by following [this example here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-app-logic/tree/master/server/middleware)

I placed the `datetime.js` file in my `server/middleware` folder and try to use it in my server.js (according to the [documentation on Middlware here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+middleware;jsessionid=852F6F06B572D4A16648DCCD69665792#Definingmiddleware-Definingamiddlewarehandlerfunction)):

```
var datetime = require('datetime');
app.middleware('initial:before', datetime());
```

However, when I try to start the app by '`slc run`', I got complaint that

**Error: Cannot find module 'datetime'**

So I suspect if the server can even detect the middleware 'datetime'. What is the right way of using custom middleware in loopback?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to require datetime using a relative path. The server will not automatically figure out dependency paths for you.

```
 var datetime = require('./middleware/datetime');
```